# External Control of system or config setting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is the alternative option to pass the connection string in below vb code to get rid of external Control of system setting

```
Protected ConnectString As String
ConnectString = Session ("Oracle_ConnectString").ToString()
Dim OracleConnection_A As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConnectString)
```

It says never allow untrusted data and validate untrusted input using central data validation to fix the flaw.. please guide to fix this error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, for desktop or web, we always used the project property->settings, and used this:

[image]

I WOULD NOT use session() as that can be rather flakey.

Any setting you use above? Well, now you can use either the configeration manager, or just use the built in class that VS generates for you!!!

So in code, use the settings class (which is automatic created for you).

Then your code to say load up a grid would look like this:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData = New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, I used the My.Settings for this.

And if you look, that setting is shoved into web.config for you.

And REALLY nice is that project settings has a connection string wizard/builder that you can use - so no need to build + create the connection string - VS will do all the dirty work for you.

And, if you want, I suppose you can use the confirmation manager.

So, in the code you have "Imports System.Configuration"

So now this:

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters", conn)
```

can be this:

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TEST4").ConnectionString)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters", conn)
```

ETC.

So, you can manually enter the connection strings into the web.config, but I would suggest that using the My.Settings class (which is automatic built for you) is a far easier approach here. The nice part is the project->properties settings can also have simple number settings, tax rates - even the company name or whatever. Once again, this is really like app-settings in a desktop application. And while sometimes I don't like these obfuscated class systems? For application settings? I think it is a great idea, and better yet it means the years of doing this say for desktop applications now is exactly the same approach for web based applications.

but, no, I don't suggest using session() for connection strings - a bad idea, and bad place since session() can be lost quite easy - especially if you using memory based vs sql server based ones.

Comment: Too funny! - the spell checker ate that one nice, did it not? I have corrected that - thank you.